# Combine Any Web Server With Any Server Application's Language

Tags: nginx, iis, webserver, programming-languages, application-server

I am new to server side programming, so please excuse me if my question seems obvious or ridiculous.

I am testing different back end options, like a language of a server (PHP, ASP.NET, Node.js, Python, Ruby and Go) and web servers (Apache, nginx, IIS...).

I am doing this to find the optimal language and web server for a monitoring web app. The server should grab data from a DB (updated independently by another app) upon a client's request, and return it back to the client (just as a background, it has nothing to do with the question).

My question now is as described in the title, can I use any web server with any application server's language?

For example, to use nginx with let's say ASP.NET (I know very well ASP.NET goes with IIS, I am just trying to give an extreme example)?

If the languages are not compatible with any web server, then, please explain to me with which each of the following languages is compatible with which web servers (the most recommended ones) and why:

- PHP
- ASP.NET
- Node.js
- Python
- Ruby
- Go

Again, sorry if it is about cars and I am asking about bikes. And Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's best to consider the framework and the programming language as completely different concepts, even if they often go hand in hand. E.g. Python is a programming language whilst ASP.NET is a framework. You can program ASP.NET framework applications for example in C#, VB, or even in Python. And if you were to choose a programming language, say Python, you can use Django, web2py and TurboGears for Python based web applications.

For web servers, it depends what kind of integration with the programming language you wish. More integration isn't necessarily better. Apache can run a PHP module, which is tightly integrated. Nginx can run PHP web apps using fastcgi, which allows you to run the PHP code as an external process. Even though Nginx using fastcgi isn't as tightly coupled as in Apache, it's not necessarily slower or worse! In many cases, the main web server (e.g. Nginx) is only a proxy for the actual web server, where the Nginx proxy handles latest web protocols such as HTTP2, SSL and compression support. This way the application's main web server can be reasonably simple. This is how ASP.NET core Kestrel web servers work: it's a very simple barebone web server with little to no support for latest and more advanced web protocols. Instead, Kestrel relies on the proxy to offer these services.

So, to answer your question, **you can use practically any general purpose web server as your main web server for any programming language/framework** assuming the web server is either 1) a proxy to an external web service, 2) the language support is built in or as bundled modules (e.g. Apache+PHP) or 3) supports using interfaces such as cgi/fastcgi (e.g. Nginx+PHP or Apache+Pyhthon). IIS for example can run .NET 4.x apps natively, .NET core using proxy and PHP using fastcgi.

However, entirely different question is whether it's a good idea to combine any language with any web server. Some combinations are badly supported or might have slower performance.

**My recommendation is to look at the question from the other end: Choose your language first, then choose from the frameworks available to that language, and then, depending on support, the suitable web server.** If you want flexibility, use a proxy. Using e.g. Nginx as a front facing proxy, you can have multiple web servers running using different programming languages on the same computer. With the proxy, all these will play nicely and you can have multiple websites originating from the same IP address.